# Simplifying repetitive code in R - how to avoid copy-pasting?

Tags: r

I am learning how to use loops and functions to avoid copy-pasting code. I'm having a hard time with this example though; how would you reduce this?

```
  train$Name <- replace(train$Name, train$Name == "crop", 1)
  train$Name <- replace(train$Name, train$Name == "pasture", 2)
  train$Name <- replace(train$Name, train$Name == "secondary forest", 3)
  train$Name <- replace(train$Name, train$Name == "mature forest", 4)
```

#edit:
I also have another part of code with a similar issue:

```
  bands <- c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7')
  
  filepaths <- paste0('./raw_data/LE07_L2SP_012054_20100211_20200911_02_T1/LE07_L2SP_012054_20100211_20200911_02_T1_', 'SR_', bands, '.TIF')
  bandlist <- lapply(filepaths, raster)
  ...
  landsat <- bandlist %>% reduce(inner_join)
  saveRDS(landsat, 'landsat_2010.rds')
```

for example, here I want to go over several files, process them and save them as new dataframes named after their respective years. Is there a way to reduce this - naming each file with its corresponding year?

Comment: One common way, given what you want to do, is to convert to factor, then to numeric. Try, `train$name <- as.numeric(factor(train$name))`. This is is because you want numeric output. If you want to rename your variable levels with other names, you can use `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: That is definitely a smarter way of solving this issue. Still though, I'm thinking also of other parts of my code that I have similar issues (for example, one that I need to create several dataframes with different names depending on the input file) ; I'll edit and post another example on the question to make this a bit clearer.

Comment: I see; i'll look into case_when. thank you!